# 単語を十個 or 十個単語を - quantifiers before or after direct objects

Tags: grammar, syntax

I once read a Japanese sentence:

> 仮に毎日**単語を十個**覚えるとする

Can I say this instead?

> 仮に毎日**十個単語を**覚えるとする

Comment: These questions are unrelated, especially the last one. (Plus ヨローパ is not a word in Japanese...) Could you separate these questions?

Comment: @Earthliŋ I think that this was a typo; it should probably be [ヨーロッパ](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%83%A8%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AD%E3%83%83%E3%83%91).

Comment: I removed the other questions.  Please feel free to ask them separately.

Comment: 十個 is an adverb.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, the two sentences are equally natural, and identical in meaning.

Comment: Only on the condition that one understands 「十個単語」 could not be used all by itself to mean "ten words".